# Laravel - How to update Input Array without deleting Sales Detail

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 project, I have this controller for Input Field Array Update.

Controller:

```
public function update(UpdateSaleRequest $request, $id)
{
    try {
        $sale = Sale::find($id);
        $data = $request->all();
        $update['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['date'])); 
        $update['company_id'] = $data['company_id'];
        $update['name'] = $data['name'];
        $update['remarks'] = $data['remarks'];
        $sale->update($update);            

        SaleDetail::where('sale_id', $sale->id)->delete();

        foreach ($data['invoiceItems'] as $item) {
            $details = [
               'sale_id' => $sale->id,
               'item_id' => $item['item_id'],
               'employee_id' => $item['employee_id'],
               'quantity'  => $item['qty'],
               'price' => $item['cost'],
               'total_price' => $item['cost'] * $item['qty'],
               'sale_type_id'=>$item['sale_type_id'] 
            ];
            $saleDetail = new SaleDetail($details );
            $saleDetail->save();
        }

    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        throw new HttpException(500);
    }
    return response()->json($sale);
}
```

In the form, the user can add more Sales Detail or remove.

Some of the SaleDetail fields are being used somewhere else.

Is there a way to update the input field array without deleting the SaleDetail as shown in what I did here:

> SaleDetail::where('sale_id', $sale->id)->delete();

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that every time a user updates sales details , you would like to update the sales details table without creating a duplicate ?? is the relationship between `Sale` and `SaleDetails` one-to-one ??

Comment: Yes @alithedeveloper, you are correct. This is because, it will need the SaleDetails somewhere else. It is one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to restructure your code so that's easier to edit. I've left some comments. I can really recommend [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru). There you will find many ways to improve your code so that it is more extensible, maintainable and testable. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

```php
class Sale extends Model 
{
    // Use a relationship instead of building your own query

    public function details() {
        return $this->hasMany(SaleDetail::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class SaleDetail extends Model
{
    // Use a computed property instead of manually calculating total price
    // You can access it with $saleDetail->totalPrice

    public function getTotalPriceAttribute() {
        return $this->price * $this->quantity;
    }
}
```

```php
class UpdateSaleRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation() {
        $this->merge([
            // Create a Carbon instance by string
            'date' => Carbon::make($this->date)
        ]);
    }

    public function rules() {
        // Your validation rules
        // Please also validate your invoice items!
        // See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays
    }
}
```

```php
// We let Laravel solve the sale by dependency injection
// You have to rename the variable name in ihr web.php
public function update(UpdateSaleRequest $request, Sale $sale)
{
    // At this point, all inputs are validated!
    // See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

    $sale->update($request->validated());

    // Please ensure, that all properties have the same name
    // In your current implementation you have price = cost, be consistent!

    foreach($request->input('invoiceItems') as $invoiceItem) {
        // How we can consider that a detail is already created?
        // I assume that each item_id will only occur once, otherwise you'll
        // place the id of each detail in your update form (e.g. in a hidden input)

        $candidate = $sale->details()
            ->where('item_id', $properties['item_id'])
            ->first();

        if($candidate) {
            $candidate->update($properties);
        } else {
            $sale->details()->create($properties);
        }
    }

    // A JWT-Exception should not be necessary, since your authentication
    // will be handled by a middleware.

    return response()->json($sale);
}
```

I have not tested the code, few adjustments may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a method called `updateOrCreate` as follow

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    return tap($this->firstOrNew($attributes), function ($instance) use ($values) {
        $instance->fill($values)->save();
    });
}
```

That means you could do some thing like

```
public function update(UpdateSaleRequest $request, $id)
{
 try {
      $sale = Sale::find($id);
      $data = $request->all();
      $update['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['date'])); 
      $update['company_id'] = $data['company_id'];
      $update['name'] = $data['name'];
      $update['remarks'] = $data['remarks'];
      $sale->update($update);            

    foreach ($data['invoiceItems'] as $item) {
        $details = [
           'item_id' => $item['item_id'],
           'employee_id' => $item['employee_id'],
           'quantity'  => $item['qty'],
           'price' => $item['cost'],
           'total_price' => $item['cost'] * $item['qty'],
           'sale_type_id'=>$item['sale_type_id'] 
        ];
        
        $sale->saleDetail()->updateOrCreate([
           'sale_id' => $sale->id
        ], $details);
        
    }

   } catch (JWTException $e) {
      throw new HttpException(500);
   }
   return response()->json($sale);
}
```

I would encourage you to refactor and clean up your code.You can also read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts